# How do you consume a scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer over py4j

Tags: py4j

I'm attempintg to consume a [`SparkListenerJobStart`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/scheduler/SparkListenerJobStart.html) object in Python, but the py4j bindings do not understand [`ArrayBuffer`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.1/scala/collection/mutable/ArrayBuffer.html)s (or, I guess, [`scala.collection.Seq`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0/scala/collection/Seq.html)s in general). What do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert the object like so:

```py
list = [arrayBuffer.apply(i)
        for i in range(arrayBuffer.length())]
```